# I created a custom FAB (floating action button) that's used to navigate to various screens. How to remove the swipe effect from stack navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

And another question I have is how do I add the component to all of the screens that I have?

```js
const ButtonDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

const ButtonNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <ButtonDrawerNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
      <ButtonDrawerNavigator.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
      <ButtonDrawerNavigator.Screen name='Project' component={ProjectScreen} />
      <ButtonDrawerNavigator.Screen
        name='AddProject'
        component={AddProjectScreen}
      />
      <ButtonDrawerNavigator.Screen
        name='QueueProject'
        component={QueueProjectScreen}
      />
      <ButtonDrawerNavigator.Screen
        name='Settings'
        component={SettingsScreen}
      />
    </ButtonDrawerNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: one way is to add that component to Root component - example: App.js

Comment: if you want to remove transition effect when you navigate between screens you can add animationEnabled: false, to your stack screen options where you want. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animationenabled

Comment: if possible can you provide expo snack for your code so it will be easy to fix any problem.

Comment: Thank you so much @LakshmanKambam I used the animationEnabled: false, now there's no sliding effect. Now I have other questions that have been raised: Like how to create a bottomTabNavigator effect without having the tabs since I don't want to have a stack where you have to go back. In addition, I noticed that when I converted the FAB's open/close toggle into a global state, it wasn't closing, but it simply opened

Comment: posted it as answer to your question. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to remove transition effect when you navigate between screens you can add

`animationEnabled: false`,

to your stack screen options where you want.

[reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animationenabled](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animationenabled)

> Whether transition animation should be enabled on the screen. If you
> set it to false, the screen won't animate when pushing or popping.
> Defaults to true on iOS and Android, false on Web.